# Restaurar una Base de Datos Oracle en otra unidad de disco en Windows Server 2012

Tags: base-de-datos, oracle

Mi pregunta es sobre lo siguiente, se requiere que pase una base de datos de Oracle Database 10g Express Edition a 11g.Me entregaron el backup en un pendrive, es un archivo con extensión .dmp (Dump file).

Instalé en un nuevo servidor la versión 11g Express Edition pero también se instaló la base de datos que viene con este (XE).

Quiero restaurar la base de datos proveniente del 10g en otra unidad diferente de C, que es donde está instalada la base de datos de Oracle 11g. También quiero que esta nueva base de datos "reemplace" al XE (no sé si es la forma correcta de decirlo).

Solo he encontrado ajustes y cambios de ubicación pero solo dentro de la misma unidad.

Cualquier alcance sería muy útil.

Gracias.

Comment: Lo que te pasaron fue un "export" de la base de datos, faltaria saber si fue con el clasico exp o fue con el expdp, deberias de investigar eso primero. Despues seria ver como quieres importar eso a la BD, si es full, si es solo un esquema o asi. La forma mas facil creo yo, seria que importaras solo los esquemas que necesites, si vas a usar la BD que acabas de crear, crea desde antes los tablespaces en la unidad que deseas y ya con eso no tendras problemas.

Comment: El backup fue realizado con el exp, y por ende solo puedo usar el imp, de hecho ya hice la restauración. Se restauró todos los objetos de un determinado esquema, pero este en su origen está en el tablespace USERS y lo que yo deseaba era que se restauraran en otro tablespace, por eso previamente había creado un usuario, un tablespace y un datafile en el disco D, pero el FROMUSER y TOUSER del imp no me sirvió, sigue restaurándose en el tablespace USERS.

Comment: Hace muchos años creo que pase por algo similar, puedes tratar:
Crear el nuevo usuario y con su nuevo tablespace, REMOVER los privilegios del tablespace USERS y asegurarse de solo tener en el nuevo Tablespace. 
Ejecutar el export con el usuario a importar (No usar sys o system) En teoria esto debe de crear los objetos en el nuevo TS.